# Connect IOS device to Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, device

This could be a noob question, but as a new ios "developer" I want to know how to connect my ios device to xcode?

I Need to find out how my new app looks on a device, and if it works!

Do I need to register my device on the apple dev programm? Or I could connect any device?

Sorry if this is a answered question here.

Comment: Have you registered as a paid apple developer? https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/

Comment: I´m registered as a student apple developer. Unfortunately I can´t add devices myself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's been a few years but I believe you need to contact the account administrator. You can't test on a device unless it has a valid provisioning profile on it and you need a paid developer account to do that or in your case contacting your account administrator to arrange having the device added. Also you should have included that in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the device to apple developer portal (you must be a registered, paid developer to test on a real device). And after that connect the device, open xcode organizer and set the device as developer device (so you can see logs while running your app on it). More info can be found here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Comment: Yeah agreed that's basically the general way of doing it. I believe you can just click the set as developer device and it will add it to the apple developer portal and the team provisioning profile so no need to add it to the portal beforehand.

Comment: I think you are right. Especially in Xcode 5 this procedure seems to work the way you described.

Comment: You basically nailed it though so no reason for me to be adding another answer that you have already answered +1

Answer (score 0):

To connect an iDevice you have to be enrolled in Apple's Developer Program. You can then register your iDevice on the dev. portal and will be able to connect it via the Xcode Organizer to your IDE.

You can then select this device on the top left side of your Xcode project to run your build on this device.